# roslib.message.get_message_class python node error

Tags: ros, roslib, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to know the class of message giving message type via following one code line. I run this python node on(Fuerte/Ubuntu 12.04) and get following error while the same code does not give any error when I run it on (electric Ubuntu 10.04).

error:

```
msg_class = roslib.message.get_message_class(self.topic_type)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Do I need to update roslib?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50167/roslib.message.get_message_class-python-node-error/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have the following import:

```
import roslib.message
```

(not just `import roslib`).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-12-11**:
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roslib.message.get_message_class` is definitely provided by Fuerte's roslib. Did you maybe just forget to import it?

```
import roslib.message
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-12-11**:
You beat me to it! :-)